# rails can this model code be refactored?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, refactoring

I would like to combine the finders better.

```
if params[:sort]
  if params[:sort] == 'industry_id'
    if params[:industry_id]
      @companies = Company.find_all_by_industry_id(params[:industry_id], :joins => "left join industries ind on industry_id = ind.id", :order => "ind.name" + " " + sort_direction)
    else
      @companies = Company.all(:joins => "left join industries ind on industry_id = ind.id", :order => "ind.name" +  " " + sort_direction)
    end
  else
    if params[:industry_id]
      @companies = Company.find_all_by_industry_id(params[:industry_id], :order => sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
    else
      @companies = Company.all(:order => sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
    end
  end
else
  if params[:industry_id]
    @companies = Company.find_all_by_industry_id(:joins => "left join industries ind on industry_id = ind.id", :order => "ind.name" + " " + sort_direction)
  else
    @companies = Company.all
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be an `industry_id` somewhere in this line of code: `Company.find_all_by_industry_id(:joins => "left join industries ind on industry_id = ind.id", :order => "ind.name" + " " + sort_direction)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have following model:

```
class Company
  belongs_to :industry

  def self.search p
    opt = {:conditions => {}}
    opt[:order] = (p[:sort] == "industry_id") ? "industries.name" : p[:sort]
    opt[:order]+= " " + (p[:sort_direction] || "ASC") if opt[:order].present?
    opt[:conditions][:industry_id] = p[:industry_id] if p[:industry_id].present? 
    if (p[:sort] == 'industry_id') or p[:industry_id].present?
      opt[:include] = :industry
    end
    all(opt)
  end
end

class Industry
  has_many :companies
end
```

Now you can use the `search` method in your controller:

```
Company.search(params)
```

Comment: I just switched to this.  Love a model based approach.  Much better for my rspec testing too.

Comment: Note - I changed `p[:sort_direction]` to `p[:sort_direction]` as my view passes sort_direction in as a parameter.  Make sure you match those appropriately if using this answer :)  Michael.

Answer (score 2):

Am I missing something or does it all boil down to this?

```
sort_joins = { 'ind.name' => 'left join industries ind on industry_id = ind.id' }
if params[:sort] == 'industry_id' || !params[:sort]
  sort_column = 'ind.name'
end

sort_column = nil if sort_column && !params[:industry_id]

options = { }
if sort_column
  options[:sort]  = "#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}"
  options[:joins] = sort_joins[sort_column] if sort_joins[sort_column]
end
if params[:industry_id]
  @companies = Company.find_all_by_industry_id(params[:industry_id], options)
else
  @companies = Company.all(options)
end
```

Comment: Thanks mu.  I always appreciate your answers and I was very grateful when I saw your replies on my q's :)

Comment: @Michael: Pushing it down to the model (as suggested by KandadaBoggu) is also a good idea.

Comment: Yes, model based is certainly better.  I did find yours a bit more readable though so it was a close call!  I wonder if KandadaBoggu's could be reduced a bit, maybe some ternary's, etc. if still readable.

Comment: Actually I had a few problems and could not get this to work.  In the end I tried the model based approach from KandadaBoggu's and it worked better.  Some, hmmm, I am going to switch my answer to that.  I hope you don't mind as you did suggest it too. Sorry I don't have time to dig into what the issues where but I kept getting unknown key sort or columns just didn't sort and I just don't have time to dig further.  But as you say model based is better :)